# Overlapping images animation effect while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I got inspired to create this animation effect. What I want to achieve is that the overlapped images get a little bigger when scrolling down and then again smaller when I scroll back.

For the scrolling part I know I need to use Intersection Observer API. I think I managed it to do right but I cant get it to work. I use React Typescript with inline styling.

The original animation - [Three overlaping images](https://coolcssanimation.com/scroll-animation-handbook/) - getting bigger on scroll down:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/OJvWvXy)

**My **React** Code**  - **OverlappingImages.tsx** :

```
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    container: {
        position: 'relative',
        height: '400px',
        margin: '0 50px',

        div: {
            width: '380px',
            border: '1px solid #000',
            overflow: 'hidden',
            lineHeight: 0,
            transition: 'transform .4s ease-in-out',

            img: {
                width: '100%',
                fontSize: 0,
            },
        },

        img1: {
            left: '5%',
            top: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: 'rotate(-4deg) translateY(20%)',
            transitionDelay: '0s',
        },

        img2: {
            left: '50%',
            top: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, 0)',
            transitionDelay: '.1s',
            zIndex: 1,
        },

        img3: {
            right: '5%',
            top: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            transform: 'rotate(4deg) translateY(20%)',
            transitionDelay: '.2s',
        },

        ' &.active': {
            img1: {
                transform: 'rotate(-6deg) translateY(50%) scale(1.9)',
            },

            img2: {
                transform: 'translate(-50%, -2%) scale(1.2)',
            },

            img3: {
                transform: 'rotate(6deg) translateY(24%) scale(1.2)',
            },
        },
    },

    body: {
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        fontSize: '48px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        letterSpacing: '1px',
        margin: 0,
    },

    section: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        padding: '500px 0',

        '&:nth-child(odd)': {
            background: '#eee',
        },
    },
};

function OverlappingImages() {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.container');
    const className = 'active';

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        (entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                    wrapper.classList.add(className);
                    return;
                }

                wrapper.classList.remove(className);
            });
        },
        {
            threshold: 1,
        }
    );

    observer.observe(wrapper);

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <p>(scroll down!)</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div style={styles.container}>
                    <div style={styles.container.img1}>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img1" />
                    </div>
                    <div style={styles.container.img2}>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img2" />
                    </div>
                    <div style={styles.container.img3}>
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img3" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p>(scroll up!)</p>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}

export { OverlappingImages };
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72730872/widen-image-on-scroll-down-using-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `styled-components` approach:

1. I created dummy data for the loop.
2. Created simple components for **section**, **figure** and **img**.  I used **figure** as a wrapper.
3. Replaced all necessary style from **img** to **figure** and changed styled logic from `position: absolute` to **grid** solution. It will allow us to keep the images in the center of the screen if screen size is large and make it flexible for the small screens.
4. The **PictureWrapper** (**figure**) can pass 2 props, position and state.

[image: resize]

[image: scroll]

##### OverlappingImages.tsx

```js
import { useRef, useEffect, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import data from "./data";
export type TypePosition = "left" | "center" | "right";

interface IProps {
  position: TypePosition;
  active: boolean;
}

const Image = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
`;

// Left image wrapper style with active, inactive state
const left = (active: boolean) => css`
  ${!active && css`transform: rotate(-4deg) translateX(calc(-1 * clamp(25%, 20vw, 75%)));`}
  ${active && css`transform: rotate(-6deg) translateX(calc(-1 * clamp(25%, 20vw, 75%))) scale(1.2);`}
  transition-delay: 0s;
  z-index: 1;
`;

// Center image wrapper style with active, inactive state
const center = (active: boolean) => css`
  ${active && css`transform: scale(1.2);`}
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  z-index: 2;
`;

// Right image wrapper style with active, inactive state
const right = (active: boolean) => css`
  ${!active && css`transform: rotate(4deg) translateX(clamp(25%, 20vw, 75%));`}
  ${active && css`transform: rotate(6deg) translateX(clamp(25%, 20vw, 75%)) scale(1.2);`}
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  z-index: 1;
`;

// Image wrapper component with 2 props:
// position: left | center | right
// active:  true / false
const PictureWrapper = styled.figure<IProps>`
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: clamp(200px, 40vw, 380px);
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  ${({ position, active }) => position === "left" && left(active)}
  ${({ position, active }) => position === "center" && center(active)}
  ${({ position, active }) => position === "right" && right(active)}
`;

const Container = styled.section`
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 50px;
`;

export const OverlappingImages = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  const callback = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      setActive(entry.isIntersecting);
      return;
    }
    setActive(false);
  };

  const options = useMemo(() => ({
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.75
  }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = ref.current;
    // Observer with external callback function and options
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
    if (container) observer.observe(container);

    //cleanup when a component unmounted
    return () => {
      if (container) observer.unobserve(container);
    };
  }, [ref, options]);

  const images = data.map((img) => {
    return (
      <PictureWrapper key={img.id} position={img.position} active={active}>
        <Image src={img.image} />
      </PictureWrapper>
    );
  });
  return <Container ref={ref}>{images}</Container>;
};
```

##### data.ts

```js
import { TypePosition } from "./OverlappingImages";
interface IData {
  id: string;
  image: string;
  position: TypePosition;
}
export const data: IData[] = [
  {
    id: "d4a54w5s1d2sd24",
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
    position: "left"
  },
  {
    id: "ad4e5qe4545d7ew4",
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
    position: "center"
  },
  {
    id: "das54w5e1sa2dw5e5",
    image: "https://via.placeholder.com/350x250",
    position: "right"
  }
];
export default data;
```

##### App.tsx

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { OverlappingImages } from "./OverlappingImages";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section>
        <p>(scroll down!)</p>
      </section>
      <OverlappingImages />
      <section>
        <p>(scroll up!)</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

##### sections style

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: thank you for your help, I start a second bounty to award your answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's the result:

[image: solution result]

- You need to wrap your code above `reutrn()`, into the `window.onload` because if you run it in the way your currently doing it, `document.querySelector('.container')` is going to return nothing but `null` or `undefined`
- Your container has no class or id and your trying to access it with `document.querySelector('.container')` again you'll get `null`

> Make sure you assign an id or a class to it

#### Style.css

```
#container * {
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.active  div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-4deg) translateY(20%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
.active  div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
.active  div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(4deg) translateY(20%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
```

---

#### OverlappingImages.tsx

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    position: "relative",
    height: "400px",
    margin: "0 50px",
    padding: "30px",
    transition: "all .5s ease",

    img1: {
      left: "5%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "rotate(-4deg) translateY(20%)",
      transitionDelay: "0s",
    },

    img2: {
      left: "50%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "translate(-50%, 0)",
      transitionDelay: ".1s",
      zIndex: 1,
    },

    img3: {
      right: "5%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "rotate(4deg) translateY(20%)",
      transitionDelay: ".2s",
    },
  },

  whiteSpace: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "100vh",
  },
};

function OverlappingImages() {
  window.onload = function () {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector("#container");
    const className = "active";

    let preY = 0, preR = 0;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      entries => {
        entries.forEach(e => {
          const currentY = e.boundingClientRect.y;
          const currentR = e.intersectionRatio;

          if (currentY < preY || e.isIntersecting) {
            wrapper?.classList.add(className);
          } else if (currentY > preY && currentR < preR) {
            wrapper?.classList.remove(className);
          }

          preY = currentY;
          preR = currentR;
        });
      },
      { threshold: 0.8 }
    );
    observer.observe(wrapper);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div style={styles.whiteSpace}>
          <p>(scroll down!)</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div style={styles.container} id="container">
          <div style={styles.container.img1}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img1" />
          </div>
          <div style={styles.container.img2}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img2" />
          </div>
          <div style={styles.container.img3}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img3" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div style={styles.whiteSpace}>
          <p>(scroll up!)</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default OverlappingImages;
```

---

### Second approach(using ref)

#### Style.css

```
.active div:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-4deg) translateY(20%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
.active div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
.active div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(4deg) translateY(20%) scale(1.1) !important;
}
```

#### OverlappingImages.tsx

```
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
const styles = {
  container: {
    position: "relative",
    height: "400px",
    margin: "0 50px",
    padding: "30px",

    img1: {
      left: "5%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "rotate(-4deg) translateY(20%)",
      transition: "all .5s ease",
    },

    img2: {
      left: "50%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "translate(-50%, 0)",
      transition: "all .5s ease .1s",
      zIndex: 1,
    },

    img3: {
      right: "5%",
      top: 0,
      position: "absolute",
      transform: "rotate(4deg) translateY(20%)",
      transition: "all .5s ease .2s",
    },
  },

  whiteSpace: {
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    height: "100vh",
  },
};

function OverlappingImages() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const wrapper = ref.current;
    const className = "active";

    let preY = 0, preR = 0;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      entries => {
        entries.forEach(e => {
          const currentY = e.boundingClientRect.y;
          const currentR = e.intersectionRatio;

          if (currentY < preY || e.isIntersecting) {
            wrapper?.classList.add(className);
          } else if (currentY > preY && currentR < preR) {
            wrapper?.classList.remove(className);
          }

          preY = currentY;
          preR = currentR;
        });
      },
      { threshold: 0.8 }
    );
    observer.observe(wrapper);
  },[])
    

  return (
    <>
      <section>
        <div style={styles.whiteSpace}>
          <p>(scroll down!)</p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div ref={ref} style={styles.container}>
          <div style={styles.container.img1}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img1" />
          </div>
          <div style={styles.container.img2}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img2" />
          </div>
          <div style={styles.container.img3}>
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="img3" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <div style={styles.whiteSpace}>
          <p>(scroll up!)</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default OverlappingImages;
```

Comment: I think document.querySelector is inner html and manual DOM manipulation in React is bad practice. Its exposing a risk to cross site scripting attacks afaik